# Are these the correct residuals to test for normality for a within-subjects 2-way anova?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, residuals, normality-assumption, two-way

I have data of an experiment where subjects performed a task under 4 conditions (A1B1, A1B2, A2B1, A2B2, where A1/A2 are the levels of factor `IV1` and B1/B2 those of `IV2`) with repeated measures on both factors, and I gather that one needs to account for a subject effect (`id`) — are these the residuals that should be normally distributed if I want the *p*-values of the `IV1`, `IV2`, `IV1xIV2` effects from an ANOVA to be meaningful? In R:

```
fit <- lm(DV ~ IV1*IV2 + id, myData)
residuals(fit)
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the question you mention only IV1 and IV2 and their interaction but in the code there ia another variable id. What is id?

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity!

Comment: How may subjects do you have ? A linear mixed model might be more appropriate if there are many.

Comment: Unfortunately only 7 - would that be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those are the residuals you would check for normality. However, with repeated measures, a better approach, may be to use a linear mixed effects model, which will preserve the degrees of freedom that are used by fitting the `id` variable as a fixed effect. with the expense of estimating a variance for the random effect of `id`.

7 levels should be sufficient. Obviously, more is preferable, but note that the `Dyestuff` and `Dyestuff2` datasets used as an example dataset included in `lme4` has 6 levels of the grouping variable. If you use `lme4` to fit the model in R then you can do so with:

```
lmer(DV ~ IV1*IV2 + (1|id), myData)
```

This will estimate  simple, scalar random effects for `id` and these can be extracted and checked for normality, along with the unit-level residuals.

Comment: Thank you, Robert! Just a follow-up question. Each subject performed n repetitions (trials) of each of the 4 `IV1` x `IV2` combinations. I am only entering the trial-average values when using either the anova or the LME models, yet it is correct to call this a repeated measures design – is this correct?

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you mean. Please ask a new question, giving more details of exactly how you conducted the study.